# Why we start seeing the disc on the double render geometry (when we do culling both from front and back) in three.js sample?

Tags: three.js

[image]I have done the doubleSide rendering with depthTest off. This generate the rounded disc into my geometry I am curious to know the math behind this and why this happen.

My object is not transparent as you can see in the image Please explain about this.to me.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshDepthMaterial

In this example when you turn material doubleSide and turn of the depthTest you will get to know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off depth testing then anything that is drawn later is on top of anything drawn before. Therefore if your object has parts that should be behind another part and you draw them later they will show incorrectly on top.

Comment: okay make sense, but why circular disc is there is math behind this ..?? why not any irregular shape like polygon or other. 
Or I am visually interpreting this wrong.. ?

Comment: The effect you see is due to the order in which the faces are drawn and the viewing angle. Faces drawn later will be on top. Consider a ribbon coiled like a cork-screw, and having a different color on each side.

Comment: Does Three.js have a way to draw back then front or does it only have back, front, bothtogether? I guess you can put the same model at the exact same place twice with 2 identical materials just one set to back and the other set to front. You'd need to turn on sorting and provide some sorting hint so it draws back first. Then again for a complex shape maybe that doesn't solve anything.